# Best way to keep check on memory in .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, memory

My application is document based and memory usage per document is quite high in certain scenarios. I want to keep check on memory usage and show a warning to user to close some documents when available memory is about to go out.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Good question, however I probably wouldn't bother implementing a "too many documents are open" feature as many users will automatically close / re-open your application / documents if they find that the app is becoming slow & unresponsive.  Alternatively I'd probably implement it by counting the size of / # of open documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `System.Diagnostics.Process.VirtualMemorySize64`. I don't know if it's the best or the most accurate way to do it but it is serving my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [.NET memory performance counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx).

Comment: According to the article, these counters tell information about GC. Doesn't GC only care about managed memory?

Comment: Yes the GC worries about managed memory. Considering that the question was about .NET that is not so strange. There are other counters that track other types of memory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965225(v=vs.85).aspx and you can access those using the same classes in .NET

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [Good MSDN article for Memory usage in .](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188781.aspx#S1)net